# Android Buttons at the bottom in a scrollview

Tags: android, xml, button

I have a ScrollView with a RelativeLayout.
I'm gonna have 2 / 3 buttons at the bottom, but they wont stay at the bottom.
Can anyone see where i did things wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_bygg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



        <Button
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hjem"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/neste"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Give a try by changing RelativeLayout height to match_parent.

Comment: scrollview is frame layout so why Your RelativeLaoyout should go to bottom? Dont You try to use (relative (scroll, button, button)) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you check correctly the buttons are at the bottom of the relative layout. The problem is the scrollview that is not taking full screen. Check this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_bygg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/hjem"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="@string/neste"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

If you notice i have inserted the android:fillViewport="true" at scrollview

Comment: Ahhh. Thanks alot :) That fixed my problem :) Now i can finaly continue :)

Comment: @Joakim you are welcome. if it is ok please accept it as an answer so to help others if they have same problems

Comment: I already did. Just had to wait 1 minute for it to accept it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

just try to change the height attribute of relative layout to match_parent:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_bygg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">



        <Button
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hjem"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/neste"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

use android:fillViewPort="true"....this stretches the layout to cover the entire scroll view...